# cron command not working

Tags: command-line, cron

As a super-user I `crontab -e` and add a line to source a `cronsh.sh` file like this:

```
0 0 * * * source /home/myname/cronsh.sh
```

The content of the `cronsh.sh` file is this line:

```
date >> /home/myname/cronlog.txt
```

However when I check the `cronlog.txt` file the next day, it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Cron uses `sh` as its default shell and `source` is a `bash` shell builtin command so not recognized in whatever `sh` is linked to other than Bash which is not the case for system shell (usually `dash` by default) ... On the other hand, the equivalent of for the `source` command `.` should work there, so try changing `source` to `.`

Comment: The same applies to the contents of `/home/myname/cronsh.sh` as well ... So check its syntax is `dash` friendly or alternatively tell CRON to use bash with `SHELL=/bin/bash` set before your cronjob in the  crontab file.

Comment: Thank you very much! You can put it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CRON uses `sh` as its default shell and `source` is a Bash shell builtin command so not recognized in whatever `sh` is linked to other than Bash which is not the case for system shell (usually Dash by default) ... On the other hand, the equivalent of for the `source` command `.` should work there ... See demonstration below:

```
$ echo "$0"
bash
$
$ type . source
. is a shell builtin
source is a shell builtin
$
$
$ sh
$
$ echo "$0"   
sh
$
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 11 12:03 /bin/sh -> dash
$
$ type . source
. is a special shell builtin
source: not found
```

so try changing `source` to `.` ... The same applies to the contents of `/home/myname/cronsh.sh` as well. So check its syntax is Dash friendly or alternatively tell CRON to use Bash with `SHELL=/bin/bash` set before your cronjob in the crontab file like so:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 0 * * * source /home/myname/cronsh.sh
```

It's worth mentioning that you don't generally need to source a Bash script to execute it (*unless you deliberately want it to execute in the current invoking shell and not in a sub-shell*), but a more preferred way is to invoke the Bash interpreter itself and provide the script file as an argument like so:

```
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/myname/cronsh.sh
```

... which should also work if you add a shebang to your script specifying the correct interpreter to invoke i.e. `#!/bin/bash` and then invoke the script as an executable itself after you give it execution permissions of course like so:

```
0 0 * * * /home/myname/cronsh.sh
```

... and that should save you from needing to apply the above mentioned other suggestions.